# Is it possible share session variable in snowflake dashboard across tile or set a common table for each tile in dashboard?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake Dashboard, i have to set the database and schema for each of the tile
is there a way I can do it for all at once, or if I can share a variable across the tiles?
Example

```
Tile1
SET table1 = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL_OLD.CALL_CENTER';

-- Use the session variable in a query

SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($table1);

Tile 2
SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($table1);
```

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom filter?  This would allow you to select a value that every tile in the dashboard would use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dedicated table to hold the tableName and use it inside each tile to get the value, this way you can control many other parameters like filters, select columns.

```
create table parameters(Name varchar,Value varchar);
insert into parameters values('tableName','SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL_OLD.CALL_CENTER');


Tile 1
set table_name = (select value from parameters where name='tableName');

-- Use the session variable in a query

select * from identifier($table_name);

Tile 2

set table_name = (select value from parameters where name='tableName');
SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($table1);
```